# lower the list style to fit the text css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the style of the list item to fit with the rest of the text (i.e. font size etc) but I can't seem to change it at all.

The code that the list is being created by is:

```
%ol.question-parts
   - test_question.answers.each do |answer|
      %li.question-text
         %div.question-part-description
           %p=change_math_delims(answer.question_part.description)
```

The code I have at the moment to show the list is:

```
ol {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

but I want to target the size of the lower-alpha list style...at the moment it is appearing like this:

[image: uneven a]

any ideas?

Comment: Please provide HTML as well. Preferably a JSFiddle or CodePen

Comment: You did not provide a `font-size` property so of course the list item will be smaller. Also, what's the point of telling a list item `display: list-item`?

Comment: How can we help without seeing the `HTML` for this? Please include relevant `HTML` and `CSS`. Also I see nothing that shows you have tried to change the `font-size`.

Comment: You can try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/7ukyw60y/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you wanted without code

I used `content:counter` on the `li` `pseudo-element`

```css
ol{
    list-style:none;
}

li:before{
    content: counter(list, lower-alpha)".";
  counter-increment: list;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Text</li>
     <li>Text</li>
     <li>Text</li>
     <li>Text</li>
     <li>Text</li>
     <li>Text</li>
     <li>Text</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your text and list can be separate. Are you creating the list in your HTML like this: ?

```
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hzfooyrw/1/)

Comment: No, I'm not creating it like that which is why I don't know how to target it. I've edited the question to include the code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @shA.t As you can see, I have provided the author with a JSFiddle link to my way of solving her problem. So my answer is valid.

Comment: @BogdanLazar I think if you add some more details to your answer and don't ask question from OP in your answer, It will make us clear that you are answering the question ;).